# Correct dumbbell upright row with externally rotation

Tags: weightlifting, trapezius

Let me tell you a little bit of background first. At first, I have found a video on ATHLEAN-X, which is [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fq67opsS_hc), that warns against doing doing barbell upright row. This is because the exercise will causes shoulders to internally rotate while lifting weights and in turns leads to shoulder impingement. At around [3:58](https://youtu.be/Fq67opsS_hc?t=238), the trainer goes on to say that dumbbell version of the upright row allow shoulder to externally rotate. So, what I am after is an instruction about to do it correctly.

The [first one](https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/standing-dumbbell-upright-row) I've found by googling is from bodybuilding. But by looking at the image, I think it's not quite right because it looks like shoulder would still internally rotate if I follow this instruction. The [second one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3L2UfTeuz3E) clearly rotate shoulder externally, but I doubt whether doing it this way will work the same muscle groups as it supposed to be in the barbell version. Specifically, it doesn't look like that it will put the load on trapezius that much.

Comment: He demonstrates the movement at 3:25. The first video (2nd paragraph) is the exact same movement as with a barbell, while the second does the same thing followed by a separate external rotation movement. It sounds like you don’t understand what external rotation is, if you are wanting to make an adjustment based on his advice then simply mimic the movement that he illustrates in the very same video.

Comment: like @JustSnilloc says, he demos the "correct" movement. However, it's not going to give you the same effect. This is a case where you sacrifice some performance for safety. You're better off using separate workouts to target the muscles (delts and traps) if you don't want to do upright barbell rows.

Comment: @JustSnilloc I am not sure if saying thanks contradict the policy of SE, but I would like to say thank you.